# Within a Clojure project using deps.edn, where is the package name and version tracked?

Tags: clojure, jvm, pom.xml, deps-edn

Where would one track/store the package name and version string within a Clojure project using `deps.edn`? For example, within a Rust project, there is the `Cargo.toml` file where the package name and version string are stored along with other metadata about the package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not there. The `deps.edn` file is not a comprehensive description of your project, it's a file for specifying what the project's dependencies are, where to get them, what classpath the project has, and how to run it.

Project name and version *can* be stored there as e.g. JVM options under some alias, but that's... unconventional to say the least.
You'd be much better off creating a completely separate file and using it however you like. An EDN file with a map with `:name` and `:version` keys, a properties file with two keys, specially marked sections in your README, an existing `package.json`, a `pom.xml` created and updated with `clj -X:deps mvn-pom` where you keep the version and the groupId/artifactId of your project, and so on.

And also, not every project needs a version and a name. While libraries do need them (and then `pom.xml` usually makes the most sense), apps often don't.

Comment: `build.clj` is probably the most common place these days for group/artifact/version?